# animating text in a UITextView on top of a UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation

I'm writing an app for iOS6, using the Interface Builder, that displays text (from an array of texts) in a UITextView on top of a UIImageView.  The user can swipe right or left to change to another text in the array.

Right now I'm using the following code:

```
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.25;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromRight;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:self.text];
```

and the entire screen is animated when the user swipes, UITextView, UIImageView, and all.  How can I make only the text move left and right when the user swipes but leave the UIImageView in place?

Comment: when should the text change? when user swipes on the view or on the imageview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add animation with UITextview's layer. `[YourTextView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];`

Answer (score 2):

Use this animation for moving left:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1 
                 animations:^{
                     [yourTextView setFrame:CRectMake(-yourTextView.frame.size.width,yourTextView.frame.origin.y,yourTextView.frame.size.width,yourTextView.frame.size.height)];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     //do something after completion if needed
                     //new text to uitextView.
                 }];
```

Use this animation for moving right:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 
                 animations:^{
                     [yourTextView setFrame:CRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width+yourTextView.frame.size.width,yourTextView.frame.origin.y,yourTextView.frame.size.width,yourTextView.frame.size.height)];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     //do something after completion if needed
                     //new text to uitextView.
                 }];
```